# Python-flask/SqlAlchem TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making an autocomplete function with ajax and I get my suggestion data from my database. it get's this error: **type error: 'BaseQuery' is not callable**

cant understand that error. Any help on this.

```
 @app.route('/search', methods =['GET','POST'])
    def search():
      if request.method=='POST':
          result=[]

          search = request.form['search']
          result = Data.query.filter(Data.name.like('%'+search+'%'))
          return result
      else:
          search = ''
      return render_template("test.html")
```